# How to bold certain values in a column of a dataframe before transferring it to excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to bold only Fruits and Vegetables under product in the below dataframe using python and transfer the data to excel, in the excel the Fruits and Vegetables should be in bold. Appreciate your help!

```
df:
      Code    Product     Limit   Value
0   3A68185     Fruits  0.6     0.000000
1   3A68185     Apple   0.6     0.000000
3   3B22979     Fruits  3.5     0.430146
2   3B22979     Apple   3.5     0.430146
4   3B22979     Orange  0.0     0.000000
6   3C67260     Fruits  3.0     1.123774
5   3C67260     Apple   3.0     1.123774
7   3C71601     Vegetables  15.0    0.000000
8   3C71601     Tomato  15.0    0.000000
14  3C78910     Fruits  2.0     1.187282
15  3C78910     Apple   2.0     1.187282
16  3C82861     Fruits  64.0    0.560864
17  3C82861     Apple   15.0    0.000000
18  3C82861     Orange  49.0    0.560864
21  3D11357     Vegetables  26.0    0.000000
19  3D11357     Tomato  25.5    0.000000
20  3D11357     Onion   0.5     0.000000
23  3D51126     Vegetables  15.0    0.000000
24  3D51126     Tomato  14.5    0.000000
22  3D51126     Onion   0.5     0.000000
26  3E20062     Vegetables  1.0     0.000000
25  3E20062     Onion   1.0     0.000000
10  3E45212     Fruits  5.0     0.000000
9   3E45212     Apple   5.0     0.000000
13  3E45212     Vegetables  36.0    0.000000
11  3E45212     Tomato  35.5    0.000000
12  3E45212     Onion   0.5     0.000000
```

Expected Output:
Code    Product     Limit   Value
0   3A68185     **Fruits**  0.6     0.000000
1   3A68185     Apple   0.6     0.000000
3   3B22979     **Fruits**  3.5     0.430146
2   3B22979     Apple   3.5     0.430146
4   3B22979     Orange  0.0     0.000000
6   3C67260     **Fruits**  3.0     1.123774
5   3C67260     Apple   3.0     1.123774
7   3C71601     **Vegetables**  15.0    0.000000
8   3C71601     Tomato  15.0    0.000000
14  3C78910     **Fruits**  2.0     1.187282
15  3C78910     Apple   2.0     1.187282
16  3C82861     **Fruits**  64.0    0.560864
17  3C82861     Apple   15.0    0.000000
18  3C82861     Orange  49.0    0.560864
21  3D11357     **Vegetables**  26.0    0.000000
19  3D11357     Tomato  25.5    0.000000
20  3D11357     Onion   0.5     0.000000
23  3D51126     **Vegetables**  15.0    0.000000
24  3D51126     Tomato  14.5    0.000000
22  3D51126     Onion   0.5     0.000000
26  3E20062     **Vegetables**  1.0     0.000000
25  3E20062     Onion   1.0     0.000000
10  3E45212     **Fruits**  5.0     0.000000
9   3E45212     Apple   5.0     0.000000
13  3E45212     **Vegetables**  36.0    0.000000
11  3E45212     Tomato  35.5    0.000000
12  3E45212     Onion   0.5     0.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
def bold_categ(cat):
    return ['font-weight: bold' if i in ["Vegetables","Fruits"] else () for i in cat]

df.style.apply(bold_categ)
```